# How to retrieve only values that have 6 digit numbers

Tags: postgresql

I have following data, where 'code' comprise of total, 2 digit, 4 digit and 6 digit numbers.

[image: screenshot of the code]

I only want to sort out the code with 6 digit numbers.

The current query that I made is as below.
How should I change the part for the "Code=code"?

```sql
% sql readonly@comtrade \
select *\
from comtrade_trade where classification='HS2012' and period='2019' \
and reporter!='MX' and partner!='WL' and flow='e' and code=code and value is not null and value_1y_change>0.1 \
```

Comment: Screenshots of code are never acceptable on Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE code BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999
```

If you made the mistake to store `code` with a string data type, you could either cast to a numeric data type or use

```
WHERE length(code) = 6
```